# React Native Changes Not Loading

Tags: android, npm, react-native, packager

I am using React-Native 0.46.4 on Mac OS for Android development. I have made changes to the index.android.js but the changes are not being reflected when I load it on the device. The packager is running on port 8080 since port 8081 is taken. I have looked at the other issues such as uninstalling watchman and restarting the packager, but none seem to be working.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you give me SC or error if there are to explain your problem like he difference between before being changed and after being changed?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that react native wasn't able to launch the packager since port 8081 was already taken by McAfee. The work around was to build a release apk every time I wanted to deploy to my device.